# How do I get a distinct collection of all related objects in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this setup:

```
class ModelA:
    name = models.TextField('Name')

class ModelB:
    name = models.TextField('Name')
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

What I would like to do is get a list of all the distinct ModelA's that ModelB's have. For example my database looks like this:

```
a1 = ModelA(name='a1')
a2 = ModelA(name='a2')
a2 = ModelA(name='a3')
b1 = ModelB(name='b1', a=a1)
b2 = ModelB(name='b2', a=a1)
b2 = ModelB(name='b2', a=a3)
```

Then I would like the result of the query to be [a1, a3].

In one place, all I want is the count of the list, actually, but I figure if I can get the list counting it is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of a [reverse lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) [and `distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__isnull=False).distinct("name")
```

> You can pass positional arguments (*fields) in order to specify the names of fields to which the DISTINCT should apply. This translates to a SELECT DISTINCT ON SQL query. Here’s the difference. For a normal distinct() call, the database compares each field in each row when determining which rows are distinct. For a distinct() call with specified field names, the database will only compare the specified field names.

Comment: I'm using postgre, as it happens. Buy why?

Comment: It's just a feature that isn't available in other backends.